# What are the top schools for online part-time Masters in data science/analytics programs? Is it much better to do the program in person?

Tags: education

I am looking to get my Masters in Science in Data Science or Analytics. I will continue working during the program so it needs to be part-time. I would prefer to do an online course, but if in-person is much better, I could be open to it. So far, I found Georgia Tech and Johns Hopkins for online, part-time programs. For in-person, I could attend Georgetown part-time. Any insight you can provide regarding which of these programs would be best, if there is another school that could be better for my situation, or if any school is essentially the same would be very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Michigan University has a nice and good dual program that you get your Master in Data Science and also a MBA.
I'd take a look at MIT's Master of Business Analytics as well.

If you want to get a job, I don't think a Master is necessary. This Forbes article explains that pretty well https://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2016/07/29/4-reasons-not-to-get-that-masters-in-data-science/#160f195a40c0